# Caret, tilde, or fixed package.json for large production app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I have a large react app in production and I'm wondering if its best to use fixed versions for my packages? I've heard that using the caret (^) is a good practice, but that seems to me that it would leave the application open to more bugs?

I've googled this issue quite a bit, and there seems to be a split between ^ and fixed versions. Is there a definitive answer somewhere in the (npm) docs on what approach to use?

Comment: I dont think there will ever be a definitive answer as it depends on what packages you are using.The ^ should only install non breaking updates so if you trust the package devs there shouldnt be an issue. Obviously if your app is used for medical reason for millions of $'s in transactions I might air on the side of caution and lock down all the package versions.

Comment: Such a good question (why so few views?) Newcomers, feel free to share your opinions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During development you can choose whichever you're comfortable with, but I would recommend shrinkwrapping just before you begin testing the app, before going into production. Lock down the dependencies with:

```
npm shrinkwrap
```

> This command repurposes `package-lock.json` into a publishable `npm-shrinkwrap.json` or simply creates a new one. The file created and updated by this command will then take precedence over any other existing or future `package-lock.json` files. For a detailed explanation of the design and purpose of package locks in npm, see [`npm-package-locks`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-locks).

That way you can leave the dependencies declared in `package.json` as they are (tilde/caret), but the exact versions declared in `npm-shrinkwrap.json` will only ever be used when npm installing.

I've personally had a problem just before going into production, when a dependency declared with `~` (the stricter one) was updated and introduced a bug (which shouldn't happen for a patch/bug fix). It's only ever happened once, but I would't want to tempt fate.

You can always update your `npm-shrinkwrap.json` by first doing `npm update <package_name>` specifying the package that needs updating, then re-doing `npm shrinkwrap` to update the existing `npm-shrinkwrap.json`.

...and don't forget [`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html)